# What to return in Factory Methods?

Tags: python, oop, class, factory-pattern, named-constructor

I have a class `Node` which I want it to have multiple constructors.

I was reading online about factory methods and apparently, it is the cleanest Pythonic way of implementing constructors. My class looks as follows so far:

```
class Node(object):
  element = None
  left = None
  right = None

  def __init__(self, element):
    self.element = element

  @classmethod
  def tree(cos, element, left, right):
    self.element = element
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    # return here
```

What am I supposed to return here though? All examples I saw online had only one assignment and they would return that very assignment. I have three assignments. What is appropriate to return here?

Comment: Your code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a named constructor (factory method), you should create an object that you want to return. E.g.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element
        self.left = self.right = None

    @classmethod
    def tree(cls, element, left, right):
        node = cls(element)
        node.left = left
        node.right = right
        return node
```

Note that you don't need the class members, and having class members with the same name as instance members is a bad idea.

Comment: dont you still need a `return node` at the end?

Comment: @JoranBeasley: oops, forgot to answer the most important part of the question :)

Comment: @larsmans why don't I need class members? Is it just because they are redundant?

Comment: @Darksky: why do you think you need them?

Comment: Well just to define them. I guess its redundant so useless. Sorry I come from a C-background, just learning Python so I'm used to "define" everything. Thanks.

Comment: @Darksky: I think you mean declaring where you say defining? There are no declarations in Python. The syntax you're using causes attributes to be added to the class object.

Comment: @larsmans doesn't `self.element` add an attribute to the class object? Since it's accessed: `object.attribute` so `Node.element`?

Comment: @Darksky: `self` is not magic in any way. It depends on what is bound to `self`.

Comment: @larsmans I understand - but I am referring to the code snippet above. Self would point to the class itself in this case..

Comment: @Darksky: `self` doesn't point anywhere in your snippet, it would cause a `NameError`.

Comment: @larsmans: take `init` as an example: it gets `self` passed as an argument, which is a reference to the class object. `self.element = ...` in init in both your case and my case, will set `self.element` to something. So it does point to 'something'. So setting `element = None` and then setting `self.element = ...` in init will override `element`'s value of None to whatever is being set. No?

Comment: @Darksky: if you mean `__init__`, that gets an *instance* as its first arg, not a class object. Note that "class object" has a specific technical meaning in Python, so we might have been using different terminology.

Comment: Oh so it gets an instance. Well then `self.newVariableUsedForFirstTime` (such as `self.element` since it was not declared anywhere else previously), would that create a new variable in that instance? I believe it creates a new variable in that instance AND create a global variable in that class called `element`. True?

Comment: Don't worry about it - I guess you're too much into Python and you keep explaining everything in terms of Python for Python beginners so I'm really confused about everything you say. I will just ask a new question about this. Thanks for your answer above.